# Стрелка на кривой Безье

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Подскажите, как можно нарисовать в конце кривой Безье стрелку?
Есть множество примеров как это сделать для прямой линии ([1](http://charlespetzold.com/blog/2007/04/191200.html) , [2](http://smfd.ru/blog/wpf-arrowline-usercontrol) , [3](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/tomershamam/2008/01/23/wpf-arrow-and-custom-shapes/)), но именно для кривой у меня не получается это сделать.

Есть такой код, но отрабатывает он как на гифке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

xaml:

```
<Canvas>
  <Path x:Name="pathMain" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="2"/>
</Canvas>
```

code-behind:

```
    public PolyLineSegment DrawArrow(Point a, Point b)
    {
        double HeadWidth = 10; // Ширина между ребрами стрелки
        double HeadHeight = 5; // Длина ребер стрелки

        double X1 = a.X;
        double Y1 = a.Y;

        double X2 = b.X;
        double Y2 = b.Y;

        double theta = Math.Atan2(Y1 - Y2, X1 - X2);
        double sint = Math.Sin(theta);
        double cost = Math.Cos(theta);

        Point pt3 = new Point(
            X2 + (HeadWidth * cost - HeadHeight * sint),
            Y2 + (HeadWidth * sint + HeadHeight * cost));

        Point pt4 = new Point(
            X2 + (HeadWidth * cost + HeadHeight * sint),
            Y2 - (HeadHeight * cost - HeadWidth * sint));

        PolyLineSegment arrow = new PolyLineSegment();
        arrow.Points.Add(b);
        arrow.Points.Add(pt3);
        arrow.Points.Add(pt4);
        arrow.Points.Add(b);

        return arrow;
    }

    private void DrawLine(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point endPoint = e.GetPosition(this);

        PathFigure pathFigure = new PathFigure
        {
            StartPoint = new Point(800, 500),
            IsClosed = false
        };

        //Кривая Безье
        Vector vector = endPoint - pathFigure.StartPoint;
        Point point1 = new Point(pathFigure.StartPoint.X + vector.X / 2, pathFigure.StartPoint.Y);
        Point point2 = new Point(pathFigure.StartPoint.X + vector.X / 1.5, pathFigure.StartPoint.Y + vector.Y/ 0.95);
        BezierSegment curve = new BezierSegment(point1, point2, endPoint, true);


        PolyLineSegment arrow  = DrawArrow(pathFigure.StartPoint, endPoint);
        PathGeometry path = new PathGeometry();
        path.Figures.Add(pathFigure);
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(curve);
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(arrow);
        pathMain.Data = path;
    }
```

Если `DrawArrow(point2, endPoint)` вместо `DrawArrow(pathFigure.StartPoint, endPoint);`, то отрабатывает так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы пробовали `DrawArrow(point2, endPoint)` вместо `DrawArrow(pathFigure.StartPoint, endPoint);`?

Comment: @VladD, Попробовал. Когда перемещение идет вдоль оси Y, то все выглядит более-менее, но при перемещении вдоль оси X происходит переворот стрелки. Дополнил ответ, посмотрите результат работы на гифке.

Comment: А может, так и правильно? Попробуйте ещё выводить ломаную из 4 опорных точек для наглядности.

Comment: @VladD, Действительно, на ломанной отрабатывает как положено. Можете подсказать как сделать тоже самое для кривой?

Comment: А вы попробуйте вывести одновременно и ломанную, и кривую. (Или бросьте в меня компилируемым примером.)

Comment: @VladD, Пример: https://yadi.sk/d/e1ggmHh3zAL4a

Comment: @VladD, Нашел готовый контрол, но не могу понять как встроить расчеты в свой код. Можете помочь? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrochon/2011/01/09/custom-line-caps-in-wpf/

Comment: Сорри, у меня на работе yandex.disk заблокирован. Может, зальёте ещё куда-нибудь?

Comment: @VladD, Да, конечно. 
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5wAB/gLNvrZpZe
http://dropmefiles.com/lkgz7
https://www.sendspace.com/file/6826vv

Comment: Посмотрите в обновление ответа

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Я дорисовал опорные точки к вашей кривой (красная ломаная на анимации):

[image: анимашка]

Дело в том, что стрелка показывает правильно: направление последнего сегмента опорной линии. Стрелка и правда показывает направление касательной в крайней точке. Но ваше вычисление промежуточных точек делает слишком большой излом, поэтому видимое направление кривой слишком отличается от направления касательной.

Попробуйте поменять алгоритм выбора промежуточных точек, проблема, думаю, в нём. (Не могу предложить свой алгоритм, потому что не знаю, какая ваша задача.)

---

По поводу алгоритма, вот такой код ведёт себя намного лучше:

```
var startPoint = pathFigure.StartPoint;
//Кривая Безье
Vector vector = endPoint - startPoint;
Point point1 = new Point(startPoint.X + 3 * vector.X / 8, startPoint.Y + 1 * vector.Y / 8);
Point point2 = new Point(startPoint.X + 5 * vector.X / 8, startPoint.Y + 7 * vector.Y / 8);
```

[image: ещё одна]

---

Вот на всякий случай полный пример:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Canvas Background="Transparent"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseLeftButtonDown"
        MouseLeftButtonUp="OnMouseLeftButtonUp"
        MouseMove="OnMouseMove">
    <Path x:Name="pathMain" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="2"/>
</Canvas>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public PolyLineSegment DrawArrow(Point a, Point b)
    {
        double HeadWidth = 10; // Ширина между ребрами стрелки
        double HeadHeight = 5; // Длина ребер стрелки

        double X1 = a.X;
        double Y1 = a.Y;

        double X2 = b.X;
        double Y2 = b.Y;

        double theta = Math.Atan2(Y1 - Y2, X1 - X2);
        double sint = Math.Sin(theta);
        double cost = Math.Cos(theta);

        Point pt3 = new Point(
            X2 + (HeadWidth * cost - HeadHeight * sint),
            Y2 + (HeadWidth * sint + HeadHeight * cost));

        Point pt4 = new Point(
            X2 + (HeadWidth * cost + HeadHeight * sint),
            Y2 - (HeadHeight * cost - HeadWidth * sint));

        PolyLineSegment arrow = new PolyLineSegment();
        arrow.Points.Add(b);
        arrow.Points.Add(pt3);
        arrow.Points.Add(pt4);
        arrow.Points.Add(b);

        return arrow;
    }

    private void DrawLine(MouseEventArgs e, UIElement host)
    {
        PathFigure pathFigure = ((PathGeometry)pathMain.Data).Figures[0];
        Point startPoint = pathFigure.StartPoint;
        Point endPoint = e.GetPosition(host);

        //Кривая Безье
        Vector vector = endPoint - startPoint;
        Point point1 = new Point(startPoint.X + 3 * vector.X / 8,
                                 startPoint.Y + 1 * vector.Y / 8);
        Point point2 = new Point(startPoint.X + 5 * vector.X / 8,
                                 startPoint.Y + 7 * vector.Y / 8);

        BezierSegment curve = new BezierSegment(point1, point2, endPoint, true);
        PolyLineSegment arrow  = DrawArrow(point2, endPoint);

        pathFigure.Segments.Clear();
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(curve);
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(arrow);
    }
    private UIElement currentHost;
    private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var host = (UIElement)sender;
        currentHost = host;
        Mouse.Capture(host);
        Point startPoint = e.GetPosition(host);
        PathFigure pathFigure = new PathFigure
        {
            StartPoint = startPoint,
            IsClosed = false
        };

        pathMain.Data = new PathGeometry() { Figures = { pathFigure } };
        DrawLine(e, currentHost);
    }

    private void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Mouse.Capture(null);
        DrawLine(e, currentHost);
        currentHost = null;
    }

    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentHost != null)
            DrawLine(e, currentHost);
    }
}
```

Comment: А если не использовать касательную? Просто взять конец кривой, точку на кривой на некотором расстоянии от него и по ним нарисовать треугольник?

Comment: @VladD, Моя задача немногим отличается от примера. Есть кубики на канвасе, которые можно соединять такими стрелками. То есть стрелка вытягивается из кубика при Drag'n'Drop. Который день безуспешно бьюсь над этой задачей. Был бы благодарен Вам за алгоритм.

Comment: @maxwell это не объясняет зачем у вас выбираются такие странные промежуточные точки. Сделайте лучше последний сегмент тоже горизонтальным, как первый - будет намного лучше.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Нужна именно S-образная кривая, поэтому такие точки.

Comment: @maxwell ну так и рисуйте S-образную. Последний отрезок-то зачем делать наклонным?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Это ведь особо не меняет сути дела. При перемещении по оси X стрелка на конце все равно начинает переворачиваться.

Comment: @maxwell пожалуйста, прочитайте ответ VladD еще раз

Comment: "потому что **ее** знаю, какая ваша задача"  прошу исправить опечатку - сам не могу